# Maximum number of items in a transaction using Azure.Data.Tables

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-tableclient, azure-data-tables

We are migrating our app that uses Azure Table to the new `Azure.Data.Tables` package.

One of the migration tasks is to convert batch operations. What is the limit of items in one transaction is when calling the [`SubmitTransactionAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.submittransactionasync?view=azure-dotnet) method, as shown on the example below? The documentation does not say the maximum number.

```
var transactionActions = new List<TableTransactionAction>();

foreach (var row in items)
{
    transactionActions.Add(new TableTransactionAction(TableTransactionActionType.Delete, row));
}

table.SubmitTransactionAsync(transactionActions).Wait();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of entities in a table transaction batch is 100.

Please see this link for more details about this feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/performing-entity-group-transactions.